# If double-slash exists after host name/port in URL, strip to single slash

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have a web application that accepts uploads from a desktop application.  In the configuration, the user specifies the URL of the server path to be uploaded to.

My issue is if a user includes a trailing slash in the URL configuration, it ends up breaking the publish functionality.  How can I strip a double-slash ONLY IF it exists after the hostname/port?  Reason for this condition is we encode special characters in the URL, including forward and backslashes.

For example, in the desktop configuration

```
http://sub.company.com  
http://localhost:8888
http://sub.company.com/ 
http://localhost:8888/
```

we have a REST url that is appended so the above urls to publish are in fact

```
http://sub.company.com/server/rest/publish --> Valid, no trailing slash in config
http://localhost:8888/server/rest/publish --> Valid
http://sub.company.com//server/rest/publish --> Returns a 404
http://localhost:8888//server/rest/publish -- Returns 404
```

Is there a regex to strip the double slash and insert a single slash after the hostname/port?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will match lines where there is a double slash in the position you are looking for it

```
(https?://[^:]*[:0-9]*)//(.*)
```

You can then replace it with

```
\1/\2
```